# Shadow of CardView not visible on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

Following code works perfectly on Kitkat, but `shadows` are not visible in Lollipop.

Actually I can see shadow in Android Studio Preview, but not while running on a device/emulator. I'm using CardView for adapter of ViewPager (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="6dp">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I'm able to get the shadow effect using following code.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it also shows shadow in L version, but it is based on elevation so you can't see the shadow if card height is match parent

try **adding margin to card** if you want to see shadow

Comment: I tried adding layout_margin as well, but even then shadows are not coming.    (android:layout_margin="10dp" )

Comment: put cardview in a relative layout and give padding to that ,
then make sure that relative layout elevation is less than cardview

Comment: is carview  layout for recycler view?

Comment: I'm using card layout for adapter of ViewPager (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)

Comment: try upgrading cardview to 22.2.1,
follow these steps also:
1. make card view is the topmost view of layout 
2.remove compat padding
3.use default elevation of 2dp
4.use default corner radius of 2dp
hope this will work